# Maven resource plugin expose an image from a different path

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

I have an immage accessible from **/resources/gfx/loading.gif**

I would like to have it accessible **from /img/immage.gif**

I tried with **maven-resources-plugin** with the following config, but actualy nothing happens.

I'm curretnly building the app from eclipse.

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-loading-status</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>/src/main/webapp/img</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>/src/main/resources/gfx</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>loading.gif</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are building a WAR, you could configure the `maven-war-plugin` to include additional web resources:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>/src/main/resources/gfx</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>loading.gif</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>img</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: tnx for this will try it and let you know, if it works I will accept the answer